# Why are multiple threads getting the same "tid?"

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

http://www.cs.colostate.edu/~cs370/Spring15/Workbook/thread_ex.txt

My professor provided the above sample code (Not duplicating to preserve his IP), and I'm confused by the output.

There are two functions being used as start routines, T1 and T2, and there are two separate for loops starting new threads. There is a tid assigned to each thread that *should* match the value of t when the thread was created, but there are several threads of the same function with the same tid as seen at the end of his sample output, i.e. there are two T1 threads with the tid 1. Why is this happening? If there are 4 T1 threads, shouldn't it generate tids 0-3?

Comment: "Not duplicating to preserve his IP" -- in the US at least, copyright is particularly liberal towards uses like SO.  Please, feel free to reproduce other sources like this and cite where they're originally published.

Answer (score 4):

Your professor designed these incorrectly, `t` changes its value in the main thread and is accessed by other threads without using mutual exclusion.

Here's what `clang`'s TSan has to say:

```
==================
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=5810)
  Read of size 4 at 0x7fff193c03e4 by thread T1:
    #0 T1(void*) /home/brian/src/so/threading/ex.cpp:16 (exe+0x0000000a0497)

  Previous write of size 4 at 0x7fff193c03e4 by main thread:
    #0 main /home/brian/src/so/threading/ex.cpp:61 (exe+0x0000000a0881)

  Location is stack of main thread.

  Thread T1 (tid=5812, running) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create ??:0 (exe+0x000000045a8b)
    #1 main /home/brian/src/so/threading/ex.cpp:62 (exe+0x0000000a085a)

SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: data race /home/brian/src/so/threading/ex.cpp:16 T1(void*)
==================
```

...  followed by ...

```
T1 [0] count = 12
==================
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=5810)
  Write of size 1 at 0x7ff2f8aa2c80 by main thread:
    #0 main /home/brian/src/so/threading/ex.cpp:70 (exe+0x0000000a0964)

  Previous read of size 1 at 0x7ff2f8aa2c80 by thread T1:
    #0 T1(void*) /home/brian/src/so/threading/ex.cpp:18 (exe+0x0000000a04de)

  As if synchronized via sleep:
    #0 sleep ??:0 (exe+0x00000003f7bd)
    #1 main /home/brian/src/so/threading/ex.cpp:69 (exe+0x0000000a0952)

  Thread T1 (tid=5812, running) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create ??:0 (exe+0x000000045a8b)
    #1 main /home/brian/src/so/threading/ex.cpp:62 (exe+0x0000000a085a)

SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: data race /home/brian/src/so/threading/ex.cpp:70 main
==================
T1 thread 1 done.
```

Comment: So a new thread is assigning its value of tid when main has already incremented it?

Comment: yes, the behavior is not deterministic.  The threads could all yield and all end up with the same value, for example.

Comment: Got it. Also thanks for pointing out TSan, that looks super helpful.

So any time a parameter being passed in pthread_create() might be changed from thread to thread, I'll want to ensure it's in a mutex on it ... that gets complicated quick.

Comment: On one hand, yes it does.  I personally believe that this concept is at the heart of millions of bugs.  OTOH there are marvelously simple constructs for locking/synchronization in languages like C++, Java, Python.

Comment: TSan and ASan make using C and C++ just that much less perilous.  There's very few reasons not to use them, IMO.  `gcc` even has 'em now.

Comment: Ok, I just read the curriculum for this course.  Forget what I said about C++, Java, Python -- your goal here is to learn how these things really work, not just leverage the synchronization mechanisms themselves.  No need to embarrass the instructor, but take this as an opportunity to learn just how easy it is to get it wrong.

Comment: We just did it in Java for our last assignment, I'm learning Python in my spare time so I might get to that eventually :)